# undefined method `service_path' when adding best_in_place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I have an application that has customers and services. Customers has_many services and service belongs_to customer. In the customer show page, I can add or delete services. But I can not edit services, so I'm using best_in_place to do that. but is not working. It returns undefined method `service_path'. I will appreciate any help, I'm new in software.

here is the repository link if you want to check the whole app.

https://github.com/felixpro/ars-reclama/commits/master

I restarted the server, but it keeps returning the same error.

customer/show.html.erb

```
   <% @customer.service.each do |service| %>
      <%= best_in_place service, :process  %>
   <% end %>
```

customer_controller.rb

```
def show
    @customer = Customer.find params[:id]
    @service = @customer.service.order('created_at DESC').limit(4)
  end


  def edit
    @customer = Customer.find params[:id]
  end
```

service_controller.rb

```
  def edit
    @customer = Customer.find params[:id]

    @service = @customer.services.find(params[:id])
  end


  def update
    @service = Service.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.update(service_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @service }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :customers do
    resources :services

  end
```

Comment: Do `$ bin/rails routes`, watch exact path to _services_ resource(first column), and then add option like `, url: customers_services_path(service)`

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk beat me to it, so .... What He **↑** Said

Comment: Never used the gem, but the doc says it uses "object path" by default => _undefined method 'service_path'_ . Or `url` option should be provided.

Comment: Thank you, but it didnt work. I tried **<td><%= best_in_place :path => customer_service_path, :process %></td>** inside my partial